# Manipulating DOM elements inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Im trying to edit a link property, which is inside an iframe. The story behind this issue is that when Im navigating on mobile, an `target=_blank` is automatically added in my `a` tag, I this isn't the behavior Im looking for.
The iframe domain is different than mine, I tried to select my link those ways, but never succeed.

`$("iframe").find("a").removeAttr("target");`

or

`$("iframe").contents().find("a").removeAttr("target");`

That's the first time Im facing this issue ... Im thinking about some security reasons maybe ? Any help is appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Same Origin Policy... you can not touch the iframe from another domain.

Comment: Alright, I was thinking about that ... Thanks for replying mate.